# Why is my output coming partially incorrect in the Daily Temperature problem in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this following problem using two pointers
**Given an array of integers temperatures represents the daily temperatures, return an array answer such that answer[i] is the number of days you have to wait after the ith day to get a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, keep answer[i] == 0 instead.**

Following is my code:

```
class Solution(object):

    def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures):

        l = 0
        r = 1
        res = []
        

        while r < len(temperatures):

            if temperatures[r] > temperatures[l]:
                diff = temperatures[r] - temperatures[l]
                res.append(diff)
                l += 1
                r += 1
               
            else:
                diff = temperatures[l] - temperatures[r]
                res.append(diff)
                l += 1
                r += 1
                

        return res
```

**So for following input; temperatures = [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73] , it should display Output: [1,1,4,2,1,1,0,0] but for my code it's displaying output= [1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3].**
Where am I going wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calculates the difference between the temperatures, but the problem asks for the number of days to wait for a warmer temperature. So instead of calculating the temperature difference, you should calculate the index difference.

```
def dailyTemperatures(temperatures):
    stack = []
    res = [0] * len(temperatures)
    for i, temp in enumerate(temperatures):
        while stack and temperatures[stack[-1]] < temp:
            last_index = stack.pop()
            res[last_index] = i - last_index
        stack.append(i)
    return res

dailyTemperatures([73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73])
```

Comment: So we can't solve this example using two pointer technique ?

Comment: Plot the temperature in y axis and indices in x axis. There will be a single point in future which will be the solution for all the previous points. These kind of problems fit well with stack.
If you try to use two pointers then to get the correct answer the complexity would be O(n^2) while using stack it is O(n)